# Apache Http Client - ok in Java main, extremely slow on Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat

I found that this code is working on a standalone Java application (runnable JAR) while when deployed inside a WAR on Tomcat (8) **is extremely slow** and I can't find the reason. The runnable JAR use the same Apache Http Client library of the WAR and the same Java version (8).
I noticed that the server **does NOT return "Content-length" response header** and uses the "Chunked encoding" feature.
I enabled http wire logging and I found that in the "tomcat" case the response body (response total size is about 2MB) arrives but it is extremely slow (more then 4 minutes) while in the standalone case all the response arrives in some seconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(3000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3000)
                .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                .build();

        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier()).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
         
     try {
            HttpGet req = new HttpGet("https://someurl");
            ((HttpGet) req).setHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            ((HttpGet) req).setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(req);
            
            if ((httpResponse != null) && (httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null)
                    && (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
            }
            
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception" + e);
     }
 }
```

UPDATE: Using another http client (okhttp) I got the same "problem" and on Tomcat I got the response after 4 minutes; now I am thinking it is something Tomcat related... crazy.

```
     OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

     Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://someurl").build();

        String body = null;
        logger.info("HTTP REQUEST BEGIN");
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            logger.info("HTTP REQUEST END");
            body = response.body().string(); // here waits a lot...
        } catch (Exception e) {
                      logger.info("exception=" + e);
        }                   
        logger.info("response=" + body);
```

Comment: Setting Content-Type on a GET request doesn't make any sense (unless you are sending content, which you don't and shouldn't). Also, "Accept: */*" is pointless.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think is related to the main problem

Comment: That's why it is a comment, not an answer.